# Android layout bugs with Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen

Tags: android, layout, fullscreen

I'm using this tag in my manifest to make my app full screen without the notification bar:

```
<activity ...
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
```

My view is a LinearLayout.

It mostly works, but the layout is a bit glitchy when transitioning from screens that do have a title bar. For example, when first starting the app, the whole app layout is shifted down off the screen by the size of the notification bar (so the buttons I have at the bottom of the screen are shifted down).

Opening the options menu shfits it back to the screen normally, except if I switch to another activity that has the notification bar, and then switch back, it will be shifted down again.

Any ideas on how to fix this glitchy behavior?

I'm use Android 2.1 SDK on Android 2.3.4.